# How to get the count from a filtered MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I did a sql query as following:

```
SELECT ip ,count(*) AS count FROM Abfragen WHERE sid = 1 GROUP BY ip ORDER BY count DESC limit 10
```

The result is:

```
ip             count

52.28.9.253     35046

213.128.143.1   3860

5.10.190.222    106

52.58.240.24    58

52.58.99.201    42

81.184.0.178    30

217.159.201.54  6
```

but i want also the total record count of the result, for example here 7.

Can someone tell me how to get it? Thanks.

Comment: You want it added in every row?

Comment: The record count is simply the number of rows returned, so generally better to handle this kind of thing in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this

**Update:**

```
Select Count(*) 
From (Select `ip`,count(*) as count 
    FROM (`Abfragen` 
    where `sid` = 1 
    Group BY `ip` 
    ORDER BY count DESC limit 10) AS IP_COUNT
```

Comment: I got the error : #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias